# How to create sequential image fade?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, sequences

I am trying to create a sequential image fade in effect which would have to stop at the end of the last array image element.
currently I have this function which fades in only one element.

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks

```
function x() {
     $('#myImage').fadeIn(600, function() {
         $(this).attr('src', images[0]).css({'display':'none'}).fadeIn(600);
     });
}
```

Comment: Can you post some of your HTML? And where do you get your images array from?

Comment: var images = new Array("image1.jpg","image2.jpg","image3.jpg","image4.jpg");

Comment: <img id="myImage" src="image1.jpg" alt=""/> thanks!

Comment: You'd better update your question than add this as comments ;)

Comment: most image faders i've seen need 2 images so that you can fade one out as the other one is faded in

Comment: This version longer but more clearer: http://jsfiddle.net/HvXEP/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vubDL/6/)

```
function x(imageIndex)
{
    if(!imageIndex) imageIndex = 0;
    $myImg.fadeIn(600, function(){
        if(imageIndex < images.length) {
            $(this).hide().attr('src', images[imageIndex]);
            x(++imageIndex);
        }
    });
}

x();
```

Comment: hi, exactly, thanks. but the idea is that the last image element in the array not to dissapear, like a fallback

Comment: Updated my answer with the correct working code.

Answer (score 2):

Call your x method recursively by adding index parameter and an escape clause

```
function x(imageIndex)
{
     $('#myImage').fadeIn(600, function(){
         $(this).attr('src', images[imageIndex]).css({display:'none'})
     });
     if(imageIndex < images.length)
     {
          x(imageIndex+1);
     }
}
```

Editnote: this is now tested

Comment: This causes an infinite loop, just tried to make a fiddle and didn't look at the code first, crashed my FF :P.

Comment: Well, how about that. thanks :)

Comment: hi thanks, but this causes an infinite loop

Comment: i fixed that, but i see you already found your answer.